# How to write a SQL query for showing route information from a flight database?

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a set of flight data and I am trying to write a query (ex: recursive query using CTE) to show the No. of flights per routes, destination city, departure city, airline info, total time of delay per routes.

Currently I don't know a way to group total number of flights per route for each airline. I also have trouble grouping totaltimedelay for each airline's routes.

Sample flight data info - Four columns total (All the data below are from the fact table in OLAP database)

```
AirlineName DepartureCity DestinationCity     TimeDelay(min)  FlightID
CA            NY                 CA              9              389
OA            NJ                 TX              8              321
AA            SEA                NY              10             231
UA            NY                 CA              20             098
HA            NJ                 TX              15             321
OA            NJ                 TX              20             123


< Expected output: 5 columns > 
AirlineName DeparCity DestiCity TotalNumberofFlights TotaltimeDelay
```

Thanks a lot I hope I made it clear enough. Any sort of help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you think you need recursion to do this? aggregating would be enough

Comment: You explained what the output should look like but where did you get the data? What is CTE? What is in each table and what are the relationships?

Comment: I think i need recursion to do this because I would need to know what routes each airline carries. Of course if there's an easier way to do it I will want to learn from it for sure.

Comment: CTE = Common table expression. All data above are from the fact table.

Comment: I don't understand why you need recursion either, your table explicitly states the available routes.

Comment: It would also help to know what RDBMS you're using, what the results from the sample data should look like, and what SQL you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `GROUP BY` should be enough...

```
SELECT 
  AirlineName,
  DepartureCity AS DeparCity,
  DestinationCity AS DestiCity,
  COUNT(*) AS TotalNumberofFlights,
  SUM(TimeDelay) AS TotaltimeDelay
FROM Flight
GROUP BY 
  AirlineName,
  DepartureCity,
  DestinationCity
```

[Click here to see it in action & have a play in SqlFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84726/1)